# background image zoom in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, zooming, background-image

While I was working on the project I faced with the problem of scaling in firefox under an operating system windows. If you change the scale of the browser page with a 100% up to 90% (for example), cut off the background-image, the problem appears only in firefox and only in windows or ubuntu, on mac os is working correctly. Possibly someone faced and will suggest how you can fix this bug.

[image: http://img.ie/wl8gs.png]

example: http://jsfiddle.net/uL53nd7z/1/

```
div {
    background-image: url(http://oi60.tinypic.com/jal5wh.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add relative units to your height and width with `background-size: cover` so your image take all the content of your div. Depending on your target audience you can use `em` or `rem` so they gonna "follow" the modification of a page.

My code :

```
html {
    font-size: 12px;
}

div {
    background-image: url(http://oi60.tinypic.com/jal5wh.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 1.916666666666667rem; /*23/12*/
    width: 1.916666666666667rem;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Result [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uL53nd7z/3/)

Comment: I opened Your example and zoomed up to 90%, bug is still there. I`m using the actual version of firefox – 32.
By the way it doesn`t depend of the size of the unit, even if I set the width and height of 35px when I`m zooming the picture is still cut off.
By the way, this problem is present on many sites, for example http://www.apple.com/choose-your-country/ if you set the scale to 80% are cropped language`s icons.

Comment: Got ya, i saw the same problem in firefox. I know this not gonna be an answer but who is zooming back ? :) Nowadays people design for zoom up, just saying. And i saw just now if you zoom back at stackoverflow logo is cropped at bottom...